# undefined method `where' for Array:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

my models;

```
class Appartment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :country
 has_many :appartments
 has_many :houses
end
```

appartment controller(part)

class AppartmentsController < ApplicationController

```
def index
 add_breadcrumb "homepage", :root_path
 @country = Country.find(params[:country_id])
 @regions = @country.regions
 @appartments = Appartment.all
end
```

In the appartment index view i do created a each loop to get the correct url links.

```
.span9
  %article.chat.t_xs
    .article-base
      #container
        - @regions.each do |region|
          - @appartments.where(region_id: region.id).each do |appartment|
            .item{:class => appartment.features_to_html_class }

              %section
                .span4
                  %h2 #{link_to appartment.name, country_region_appartment_path(@country, region, appartment)}
                  %ul.stars.floatstars
                    %li.yellowstars{:style => "width: #{appartment.avg_rating * 25}px !important;"}
                  %footer
                    %br
                    %p 
                      = raw truncate(appartment.property_description, :length => 250, :omission => '...')
                      #{link_to "meer", country_region_appartment_path(@country, region, appartment)}
```

i get the error message "undefined method `where' for Array:Class" What am i doing wrong here...thanks...

ciao..remco

Comment: On an unrelated note, the correct spelling is "Apartment", one "p".

Comment: @Chowlett In Dutch, the correct spelling is "appartement." But "meer" (more) is correct.

Comment: @gg_s - fair enough, except that the other class names (`Region`, `Country`, `House`) appear to be English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Rails 3, `Appartment.all` returns an array, not an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, so you can't perform additional queries on it (like `where`). This will change in Rails 4, but in the mean time, try using `scoped` in your controller instead:

```
@appartments = Appartment.scoped
```